# Converting decimal to binary using Java JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, binary, joptionpane

In the coding I have done, I have a problem at the very end. When the program actually converts the decimal into binary form, the `JOptionPane` window separates each number in the binary answer. I don't know how to fix this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class decimalToBinary {

Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
public static void main(String [] args){

    String digit;
    String wrong = ("Enter a value greater than 0");
    String binary_answer;
    double entered_value;

    digit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
            ("Enter the decimal number: ");
    entered_value = Double.parseDouble(digit);

    if (entered_value < 0)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, wrong, "ERROR",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    else 
    {
        binary_answer = (binaryform((int) entered_value) + ".");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, binary_answer, "Result",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private static Object binaryform(int number) {
    double remainder;

    if (number <=1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, number , "Result",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        return null;
    }

    remainder= number %2; 
    binaryform( number >> 1);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, remainder , "Result",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    { 
      return " ";
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: I assume this is because you're calling `binaryform` recursively, which is showing the individual `JOptionPane`s, but you're also ignoring the return results...Perhaps you'd like to provide your expectations of how it should work...

Comment: I would like my program to ask for a positive integer that can be converted into a binary form. By doing so, I would like the JOptionPane to ask for a value in which the user can input, and then come out with that value in binary form. I know it has something to do with the return. I just don't know how to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I've noticed that you're calling the binaryform() multiple times.
You should stack the result in an array or collection before showing it in a joptionpane.

make it something like this

```
//introduce a field variable
String remainderStr='';
private static Object binaryform(int number) {
    double remainder;

    //if (number <=1) {
    //    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, number , "Result",
    //            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    //    return null;
    //}

    remainder= number %2; 
    //append on string, to display after the conversion is done.
    remainderStr =remainderStr + remainder;
    binaryform( number >> 1);
    //move this part to main
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, remainder , "Result",
    //        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    //{ 
    //  return " ";
    //} 
}
}
```

Comment: How should I do that? I've tried adding in a string but it's not working.. I have no clue how to fix this!

Comment: you have to concat/append it on a string then after the binary conversion process is done. display the final result. I've added a sample code

Comment: Can't seem to make it actually work. That's what i tried after asking the question, hasn't worked yet..

Comment: did the repeating joptionpane disappear?